# HTML textarea ignores 1st new line character, why?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, newline

Could you explain why this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write("<textarea cols='10' rows='10'>" + "\nhello\nbabe\n" + "</textarea>");
</script>
```

renders a textarea with one new line at the bottom, but **NO new line at the top**?

[image]

Tested IE8, FF11, Safari 5.1, Chrome 24

And it's not a JS issue, even when you write HTML in page you get the same result, i.e.

```
<textarea cols='10' rows='10'>
hello
babe
</textarea>
```

The 1st new line is still missing!!!

I need to add another new line at the top in order to show one:

```
document.write("<textarea cols='10' rows='10'>" + "\n\nhello\nbabe\n" + "</textarea>");
```

Comment: did u try with <br> tag?

Comment: "\n" will not be treated as textarea value, but as html breakline

Answer (score 5):

When writing inside of XHTML use proper entities.

```
<textarea>&#13;hello</textarea>
```

If a text node begins with white space (space, new line) it will be ignored by HTML parsers. Encoding the new line into a proper HTML entity forces the parser to acknowledge it.

```
&#13; == carriage return
```

Comment: It does not work on IE8, but works on Chrome 24, Safari and FF. I assume it's IE8 bug.

Comment: @Marco Demaio - IE8 may require a Line Feed (&#10) as well, since windows believes a new line "\n" is a Carriage Return + Line Feed (&#13&#10).

Comment: You've made my day. Textarea has killed an hour)

Comment: That works for me. In script:  s = s.replace(/^\n/ , "&#13;")

Answer (score 5):

Answering the question "Why". This is specified in HTML 5 specification in the chapter that describes how DOM tree is created from tags found in a HTML document.

In the current HTML 5 living standard it is "12.2 Parsing HTML documents" > "12.2.6 Tree construction" > "12.2.6.4 The rules for parsing tokens in HTML content" > ["12.2.6.4.7 The "in body" insertion mode"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody).

(In HTML 5.2 the same section is numbered [8.2.5.4.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#the-in-body-insertion-mode)).

Scroll down for item "A start tag whose tag name is "textarea""

> A start tag whose tag name is "textarea"
>   Run these steps:
>   1. Insert an HTML element for the token.
>   2. If the next token is a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character token, then ignore that token and move on to the next one. (Newlines at the start of textarea elements are ignored as an authoring convenience.)
>   3. Switch the tokenizer to the RCDATA state.
>   ...

The algorithm deals with LF characters only, because CR characters are [handled earlier](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#preprocessing-the-input-stream).

(Historically, looking into obsolete HTML 4.01 specification:
Its [Chapter 17.7 "The TEXTAREA element"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7) has an example that shows that text content for a textarea starts from a new line.
[Appendix B.3.1 Line breaks](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-line-breaks) (informative) explains that such behaviour originates from SGML.)

A line break character before `</textarea>` end tag is not ignored nowadays, in HTML 5.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, change your code to have the textarea pre-defined as html, then write the string like this instead:

HTML:

```
<textarea cols='10' rows='10' id='test'></textarea>
```

Script:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '\nhello\nbabe\n';
```

That should preserve white-space. Optionally you can add a css rule:

```
textarea {
    white-space:pre;
    }
```

A fiddle to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/RFLwH/1/

Update:

OP tested in IE8 which this does not work - it appear to be a limitation/bug with this browser. IE8 do actually use CR+LF if you manually insert a line-feed at the top, but when set programmatic this is completely ignored by the browser.

Add this to the html to do a test:

```
<span onclick="this.innerHTML = escape(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);">
    Get textarea content
</span>
```

You can see the string returned is:

```
 %0D%0Ahello%20babe%20
```

meaning the CR+LF is there (the other line-feeds are converted to spaces - but inserting a space at the beginning does not help either). I guess there is nothing you can do about this behavior; the browser is obsolete (but unfortunately still widely used so this can be a problem for those users if this is essential).

Comment: It does not work on IE8, but works on Chrome 24, Safari and FF. I assume it's IE8 bug.

Comment: Yeah, no surprise there. I did a test for ie8 (locally as fiddle cannot be shown in ie8 either) and manually inserted a line-feed at top and took the text out and escaped it to see what it contained. It *do* insert at /r/n there, but when setting it from javascript it just completely ignores it. Guess there is not much to do with that :-/

Answer (score 1):

Add a whitespace before the first "\n" like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write("<textarea cols='10' rows='10'>" + " \nhello\nbabe\n" + "</textarea>");
</script>
```

or

```
<textarea cols='10' rows='10'> <!-- whitespace here -->
hello
babe
</textarea>
```

otherwise it won't work.

---

Update:
Later in your server side, you can remove the first whitespace by doing

```
$str = ltrim ($str,' ');
```

or

```
$str2 = substr($str, 4);
```

if it is PHP.

Comment: The white space in the script renders the 1st line with a space. This is not good, data in textarea could be sent to server and they would be saved into DB with teh added space that nobody required.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `\n\r` at the top:
`document.write("<textarea cols='10' rows='10'>" + "\n\rhello\nbabe\n" + "</textarea>");`

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/duyolamo/1)

Comment: How peculiar but doing `'\n\r'` works instead of `'\r\n'` for me!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i finished with this server-side solution:

to double leading(only first!) nl symbol before output it in textarea:

```
if(str_startswith("\r\n",$value))
{
    $value = "\r\n".$value;             
}elseif(str_startswith("\n",$value))
{
    $value = "\n".$value;
}elseif(str_startswith("\r",$value))
{
    $value = "\r".$value;
}

function str_startswith($start, $string)
{
  if(mb_strlen($start)>mb_strlen($string))
    return FALSE;
  return (mb_substr($string, 0,mb_strlen($start))==$start);
}
```