# <pre> is not preserving whitespace

Tags: html, css, whitespace, pre

Why does:

```html
<pre style="background:red">
line 1
</pre>
```

render the same as:

```html
<pre style="background:red">line 1</pre>
```

The first has two more line breaks, but it seems the browser ignores them. What's the rule for this?

Comment: `<br>` will add another line, so it would look like something like this: `<pre style="background:red"><br>line 1<br></pre>`

Comment: breaks doesn't matter in html, as @RamondeVries has said, you should use <br> instead

Comment: According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element), "In the HTML syntax, a leading newline character immediately following the `<pre>` element start tag is stripped."

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Have you heard of <pre> before? Breaks sure as heck do matter.

Comment: @Alan not the first one, as you can see

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia And what about the last one?

Answer (score 4):

> If a text node begins with white space (space, new line) it will be ignored by HTML parsers. Encoding the new line into a proper HTML entity forces the parser to acknowledge it.

```
&#13; == carriage return
```

use this instead:

`<pre style="background:red">&#13;line 1</pre>`

The pre tag will keep all formatting inbetween, but not at the beginning

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529725/6852641 for more

Comment: Thanks! What about the line break preceding the closing tag?

Comment: You can read more here https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33