Jquery html() doesn't preserve first line break in textarea
I need to render some HTML coming from server, and it contains a textarea with line breaks (\n). The first line break always disappears. How to fix this?
<pre>, white-space: pre-wrap don't work.
As you can see in the example below I tried to render 2 line breaks but only one got preserved.


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").html('<textarea>\n\nthird row</textarea>');
});
textarea {height: 200px;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>



Any help much appreciated!

It's a hack, but you could just add a third line break, knowing that the first one will be lost.

Refer the reason here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529500/html-textarea-ignores-1st-new-line-character-why
HTML Parsers ignores it. So adding a white space before first line break will work.
